# php login form using where clause with session data

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmyadmin

I have created a login form that works, so the next step is to return data relative to the user that has logged in rather than the entire table. I am using a php session to parse the username from one file to another. I can echo this value without a problem, however when I try to use it in the following statement, unexpected T_STRING error is thrown. How do I parse the variable correctly.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.username = $_SESSION['user']';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.username = "' . $_SESSION['user'] . '"';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.username = '$_SESSION['user']'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try double quotes and brackets around variable

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.username = '{$_SESSION['user']}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes around query string.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.username = $_SESSION['user']";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign it to a variable.

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.username = $user";